# What's the connection between flags and mode in open file function in C

Tags: c, io

I'm a beginner in C, have a question about the flags and mode paramaters in open file function in C
so C's open function is :

```
int open(char *filename, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

and some macros for the flags are:

- `O_RDONLY`: Reading only
- `O_WRONLY`: Writing only
- `O_RDWR`: Reading and writing

and the mode bit is something like:

[image]

What I don't understand is,
let say we have a open function as:

```
fd = Open("foo.txt", O_RDONLY, S_IWOTH);
```

so `O_RDONLY` specifies that we can only read the file, but `S_IWOTH` specifies that anyone can write this file, isn't that they contradict to each other?

Comment: Minor nitpick: The signature should be `int open(const char *filename, int flags, mode_t mode);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *flags* decide the properties to be applied during opening of this file *at this time* (let's call this the "session") - this affects what you can do with the file while it's open (or, more correctly, what you can do with the file descriptor).

The *mode* decide the properties of the file should it be created as part of the opening process - this affects how anyone can open the file in future.

Your *specific* example (albeit with the correct `open` rather than `Open`):

```
fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDONLY, S_IWOTH);
```

is not really relevant since the file *won't* be created without the `O_CREAT` flag<sup>(a)</sup>.

However, had you supplied `O_CREAT`, it's perfectly acceptable to *create* the file allowing anyone to write to it, but have it opened for this session in read-only mode.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Some systems have *other* flags which may create the file under some circumstances. For example, Linux has the `O_TMPFILE` flag.

Comment: thanks for your answer. still a question, let say I first create a file fd = open("foo.txt", O_CREAT|O_RDONLY, S_IWUSR); then another application tries to open this file  fd = open("foo.txt", O_RDWR, 0); can the application writes this file? since it has been reset to read and write, but the owner(Me) only want himself to write the file?

Comment: @paxdiabio and is it a overloaded open function ony required two parameters? because when an application tries to access to an existing file, no point to set the mode bit?

Comment: @amjad, perhaps I wasn't clear. The flags apply to *this* session, the file descriptor. They have nothing to do with the file itself. You can open a file RO while creating the file as world-writable. Another process can then open the file RW and there is no cross-over between the two. Your process can still only read, the other can read and write. That's because the file descriptors are distinct.

Comment: And, no, it's not overloaded in the sense of C++ since it's basically just C, which *has* no runtime overloading. It's just that you can leave off the parameter and it will be set to some arbitrary value. Which won't matter unless you ask for it to be used by specifiying a creation flag of some type. Since that's a violation of the contract, all bets are off in that case :-) Most likely, you'll get some "random" mode.

Comment: so can I understand in this way, the mode in the first open() determine the flag in the second open function(called by others)? If I create a file using 'S_IRUSR' as the mode bit in the first open(), then others call open() using ''O_RDONLY" as flag will not be able to read the file?

Comment: @amjad: yes, assuming by "others" you mean different users rather than another process by the *same* user. The same user *will* be able to read the file. And, just a technicality, it's not that the other users won't be able to *read* the file, it's that they won't be able to *open* the file.

Comment: Note that [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) is a variadic function (`int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);`). It's perfectly acceptable to call it without a mode argument if the mode won't be used. The answer mentions `O_TMPFILE`; that is not a part of POSIX — you need to read the appropriate man page ([`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)). Since the file created by `O_TMPFILE` is anonymous (the path specified is a directory name, not a file name), the mode is not going to be relevant to that option (use `O_RDWR`).

Comment: And the Linux man page for `open()` under `O_TMPFILE` mentions [`linkat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/linkat.html) as a way of supplying a name for a nameless file descriptor.  There are likely errors such as EXDEV for cross-device operations, but it is intriguing that there's a way to reconnect anonymous files to the file system at all — and that might make the `mode` relevant after all, despite my prior assertion that it is not.